# Test for Existence of a Table

Tags: mysql, if-statement

In my SQL script, how do I test for the existence of a table in the database? I would like to do something like the following:

```
IF EXISTS test4 THEN 
  GRANT DROP ON test4 FOR 'root'@'localhost;
  DROP test4;
ENDIF
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this it'S a useful configuration to have a user that is able to do `GRANT` but deosn'T have the right to `DROP` right away... What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: I am revoking all modification rights on certain tables to make them read-only. However, when I import fresh data into those tables (e.g. table4), I delete the table then recreate it and import the data. However, before I can DROP it, I must first grant DROP privileges. Does this make sense now?

Comment: It does. If I were you, I'd still prefer to use two separate users for this, on system user that has write access and one that applications use that has only read-access - but whatever floats your boat I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to check for a table's existence for grants -- assuming you even need them.

```
GRANT DROP ON test4 FOR ?
DROP test4 IF EXISTS
```

Comment: I had "assumed" that MySQL would throw up an error if I tried to grant privileges on a non-existent table, thus causing the script to abort. I will give this a try when I get back to the office tomorrow. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you really need to add check you can use system catalog

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables 
where table_name='TABLENAME' and table_schema='DBNAME'
```

Comment: I had not thought about this approach; thank you for suggesting it. It may well come in handy soon.